# How to distribute compiled files via git automatically

Tags: git

I am working on an Electron.js application for my organization, for internal use.

I don't make and package it, because it updates very frequently and used by just a few people, it will cause overhead - it's simpler just to pull updates from the git repo.

I want to make a git repo that contains the build folder from rollup.js (and a few other files) that builds the js source code automatically every in the main (development) repo push and pushes the compiled files to the distribution repo.

How could I do something like that?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to create repos that contain build artifacts because they tend to be large and the repository will become very bloated very fast.

Comment: A better way forward is to use a package manager which will build from a Git repository. I don't know Electron.js, but [npm does this](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies).